# Getting "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" Error in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, http-post, google-cloud-functions

I have written a function in Firebase cloud functions to make a HTTP Post to the Onesignal API. I first test my request in Postman and ensured that the body and headers are correct and working - it succeeded. I then proceeded to create a post request using the [request npm package](http://getaddrinfo%20ENOTFOUND). This is what I have so far

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

const Requestbody = {
    included_segments: ['Subscribed Users'],
    app_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    contents: { 'en': 'Test Notification Body' },
    headings: { 'en': 'Test Title' }
}
httpRequest.post({
    url: 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Some Token...',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(Requestbody)
},
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) { return res.status(500).send('Failed - ' + JSON.stringify(error)); }
        console.log('Onesignal Response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        return res.status(200).send('Success');
    });
}
```

Every time I invoke this cloud function, the request.post call returns the following Error:
`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND onesignal.com onesignal.com:443`

But that URL I provided is the exact one I use to test within Post Man.

Comment: What payment plan is your project on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug Stevenson and LundinCast pointed out, I am on a plan of Firebase that does not support calls to external hosts. I need to upgrade to the at least the `Flame` plan to support that.